# Code signing cert disappearing for Microsoft Clickonce app

Tags: msbuild, ssl-certificate, clickonce, windows-server-2008-r2, code-signing-certificate

We have a clickonce app that is deployed on a schedule. The app uses a code signing cert that is in the personal store of the appbuilder account. The certificate is dropping out of the store at seemingly random times, causing scheduled deployments to fail. When build fails, we can go in, add cert again, run build and deploy as expected. By the time next scheduled deployment happens, cert has dropped and deployment fails.

Cert is not expired, and it's signed by a local CA that we setup. There are 5 other certs in the same store, that are sticking. I can't find any mention in event logs, and we're at a loss to root cause. Any pointers to get resolved appreciated.

Comment: It may be hidden by a autoenrollment trigger if there are problems with the certificate.

Comment: @Crypt32 I believe you are correct, in task scheduler, the Microsoft\Windows\CertificateServicesClient\UserTask is ran at every login and 8 hours which corresponds to the timing of the cert dropping. Now to determine why...

Comment: most likely, it doesn't pass validity/revocation checks. You can export your certificate to .cer file and run the following command against your cert: `certutil -verify -urlfetch path\exportedcertfile.cer`

Comment: @Crypt32 Seems cert was revoked. The requester is no longer employed by company, and all certs she was requester on have been revoked. Is it possible to re-revoke with "Certificate Hold" and unrevoke? Also considering removing cert or creating new cert...

Comment: I would strongly suggest to keep them revoked and provision new certificates. There might be a security problems (up to law suit) if former worker have a copy of their keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewed cert in CA server. The root cause of my issue was that the user associated with the cert is no longer an employee, so their credentials were deactivated. In turn, all the certs created by them were invalidated.

**Do not create an SSL under an employee account, use a service account for anything that might outlive your tenure.**